# Passing cookies with PhoneGap's FileTransfer

Tags: android, post, cookies, cordova

The problem with jquery.cookie and others is that they seem to work well for $.ajax(), but not for PhoneGap's FileTransfer. I have been banging my head on an issue, where I have to pass cookies along with a file. I can access and store the cookies after authentication, but they don't get passed along when I then try to post a file with FileTransfer.

Is there a way to prod FileTransfer to send cookies along?

I am developing mostly for Android.

Comment: why dont u just set cookies in the document.cookie ?

Comment: Yes. I resorted to that. The cookies now seem to be sent. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by just setting cookies in the document.cookie.